# Flink- force Checkpoint

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

- **Currently, flink application is configured and implemented to create
  avro files on every checkpoint.**
- **Is is possible to force the flink application to create avro file
  on-demand, instead of configurable time interval.**
- **Is there any REST APIs or any other java implementation and
  configuration to force checkpoint.**

**Environment**

- Flink version - 1.15.4
- Jdk 8

Answer (score 1):

> Is is possible to force the flink application to create avro file
> on-demand, instead of configurable time interval.

Assuming you are using
`StreamingFileSink.forBulkFormat` to produce in avro format, you can implement custom `CheckpointRollingPolicy` and checkpoint on processing time or on a specific event:

```
public final class CustomCheckpointRollingPolicy<IN, BucketID>
        extends CheckpointRollingPolicy<IN, BucketID> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public boolean shouldRollOnEvent(PartFileInfo<BucketID> partFileState, IN element) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldRollOnProcessingTime(
            PartFileInfo<BucketID> partFileState, long currentTime) {
        return false;
    }
}
...
StreamingFileSink
      .forBulkFormat(outputBasePath, AvroWriters.forGenericRecord(schema))
      .withRollingPolicy(new CustomCheckpointRollingPolicy())
      .build()
```

> Is there any REST APIs or any other java implementation and
> configuration to force checkpoint.

Yes, you can trigger `savepoint` without `cancel`, which will trigger `checkpoint`. The corresponding REST API endpoint is `/jobs/:jobid/savepoints`. See [REST API #jobs-jobid-savepoints section for details](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/rest_api/#jobs-jobid-savepoints)

**UPD:** It's possible to trigger `checkpoint` via a dedicated `/jobs/:jobid/checkpoints POST` endpoint. See [REST API #jobs-jobid-checkpoints-1 section](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/rest_api/#jobs-jobid-checkpoints-1) for details.

Comment: I Have tired **/jobs/:jobid/savepoints REST API** by passing ` {
    "cancel-job" : false,    
    "target-directory" :"file://temp"
} ` and it got successfuly gerneated respond {"request-id":"112"} **The Avro file not generated in the target-directory.** **How can we know the Avro file was generated at that tiggered time??** **How will we know the checkpoint trigger successfully and generated AVro???** ** Please suggest how to fix this issue**

Comment: The **/jobs/:jobid/savepoints REST API** will generates only _medata data file? The **target-directlory ** generated only the _metadata file not the Avro.  My requirement is- is it possilble to force the Avro to create on-demand?

Comment: The */jobs/:jobid/checkpoints POST* will trigger a checkpoint - see https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/ops/rest_api/#jobs-jobid-checkpoints-1. Sorry, I was under impression that the `savepoint` should also roll out new file.

Comment: /jobs/:jobid/checkpoints POST  not found in Flink version - 1.15.4 only GET method. Can you suggest is there any other way to force the Avro to generate on-demand?